# HTML 5 appcache for dynamic images

Tags: html, caching, offline

I have an application manifest working nicely now to cache my app.  However, I have one section that polls the server regularly and will render back different images depending on the state of the app.  These images are not cached (it is not realistic to consider caching them), so they show as broken whenever that ajax call tries to draw new images on the screen.

Everything works fine when I have the appcaching off... how do I allow the app to look to the web for certain files instead of only looking at the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put those files in a [`NETWORK` section](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#concept-appcache-manifest-network) in the manifest file.  Anything in the network section will always be fetched from the network.  Of course, you still have to set appropriate HTTP headers to prevent the browser cache storing those images, and any file in the `NETWORK` section will, by definition, be unavailable when the app is being used offline.